# Issue with _context.SaveChanges() method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am facing strange issue.

If I remove `_context.SaveChanges()` from `addUpdateStudentDetails()` method than nothing is saved whereas i am expecting to be saved since i do have `_context.SaveChanges()` statement in my calling method i.e. `update()`.

**Right?** Or there is soemthing else reason which is causing this?

However, if i keep `_context.SaveChanges()` in my called method than added/ or modified information saved successfully in database.

```
public void update(StudentReport report)
{
    addUpdateStudentDetails(report);
    _context.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(report);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}

private void addUpdateStudentDetails(StudentReport report)
{
    using (var context = new DBContext())
    {
        if (student != null)
            context.Entry(orignal).State = EntityState.Modified;
        else 
            context.Student.Add(orignal);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

addUpdateStudentDetails has disposed the context. Call to SaveChanges is executed on the field, not on that same context variable.

Comment: update method works on _context variable (with underscore), which is obviously declared outside of that method, probably a field.